# How to plot mosaic plot in python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, mosaic, mosaic-plot

I'm trying to plot a mosaic plot on below dataframe, but it keeps sending error: 'ValueError: at least one proportion should be greater than zero'
here is the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
```

```
Mortgage = [3839, 950]
Own = [1170, 183]
Rent = [3496, 362]
data = pd.DataFrame({'Mortgage' : Mortgage, 'Own' :Own, 'Rent': Rent})
mosaic(data, ['Mortgage', 'Own', 'Rent'])
plt.show()
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: please post the contents of the mosaic function. Or at least where it's import from (if it's from `statsmodels`). There's no way to know what you're calling

Comment: @BrianJoseph thanks Brian, I've edited the code.